# Django - How to pull a logged in users data from a database table?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-templates, django-views

I am relatively new to Django, and web development in general. Basically, I want to pull a logged in users data from a database table so he can view/edit it on a 'My profile' page.

I'm guessing the best way to do this would be to call the logged in users 'id', then somehow use it to call the row in the database table I want?

This is how far I have got, but I don't want the user's 'id' in the url, I want the users 'row id' in the database table:

urls.py

```
    url(r'^my-profile/(?P<id>[0-9]+)', my_profile, name="my_profile"),
```

views.py

```
    user = request.user
```

template

```
    <a href="{% url 'my_profile' id=user.id %}">My profile</a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

My current code:

models.py

```
    class BarSignUp(models.Model):

        LOCATION_CHOICES=(
            ("Central London", "Central London"),
            ("North London", "North London"),
            ("East London", "East London"),
            ("South London", "South London"),
            ("West London", "West London"),
        )

        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        area = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, null=True)
        booking_link = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("barber_profile", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'row id in the database table'?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki In the mySQL table I want to call the data from there are two 'id' colums, the user's 'id' and the row 'id'. In order to call the users data in the 'my profile' page I need to add the row 'id' to the url (e.g. my-profile/3). Currently, I can easily add the user's 'id' to the url using the 'user = request.user' function above, but I have no idea how to use that to call the relevant data

Comment: The `user.id` __IS__ the "row id" (value for the primary key db field `id` in your `django_user` table) - but you don't need to retrieve it from the db at all, it's already there in `request.user`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for your response. You misunderstand me: The data I want to call isn't in the ' django_user ' table. It's in a separate table to the user information. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @WillDpard how are we supposed to guess this ? You didn't post your models and explicitely stated you wanted "user's data" (quote : " I want to pull a logged in __users data__ "). Sorry but AFAICT no one here has any mind-reading abilities... If you want the right answer, starts by asking the right question.

Comment: And actually no one can answer without knowing your models and what you exactly mean by "users data".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sorry pal am very new to Django so when I said 'users data' I meant the logged in user's data in the table 'BarSignUp' - my fault. I have included my current models.py with the model I want to call the data from. Help out if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BarSignUp` model has a ForeignKey on `User`, which mean you can have zero, one, or many (for the largest possible definition of "many" - could be literally millions) of `BarSignUp` records related to one given user. If that's really what you want, then `request.user.barsignup_set.all()` will return them all (cf [the FineManual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)).

If what you want is one single `BarSignUp` per user, then you want a `OneToOne` field instead of a `ForeignKey`, and once you've updated your models you can get the current logged-in user `BarSignUp` with `request.user.barsignup` ([this is document too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/))

Comment: Thanks for this Bruno. This looks more like it. How would I actually implement `request.user.barsignup_set.all()` in my view and template. Please can you give an example? Would it be something like this: views.py `data = request.user.barsignup_set.all()` template `{{data}}` ?

Comment: This all documented, so please start with the doc and tutorial, try coding your project from here, and come back when you hit a roadblock. But just start with the code in your comment and find out what you get...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I asked because views.py `data = request.user.barsignup_set.all()` template `{{data}}` didn't work. Would be helpful if you could tell me where/how I'm going wrong here

Comment: @WillDpard please don't use comments to ask other questions - if you have another question, post a new question. Also as formulated your question will be downvoted and probably closed ("does not work" is totally useless, you have to post a MCVE and clear description of the problem). And, I insist, doing the official tutorial and reading the doc (and learning how to debug your code) will be much more productive than asking here for each and any line of code. SO is not a replacement for the doc...

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, you can get the logged-in user with `request.user`. Therefore you can remove the id from the regex and use `r'^my-profile/$'`.

Then change your url tag to `{% url 'my_profile' %}`.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's much easier! However, this still doesn't help me call data from the table I want using the user's 'id'. I can present the users id in the template with: {{user.id}} but how do I call data from another database which has users information? For example {{database_i_want_to_query:name}}

Comment: Alasdair, sorry don't think I was clear enough: The data I want to call isn't in the ' django_user ' table. It's in a separate table to the user information. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You haven't shown your models so we can't tell how to query them.

Comment: My fault: have just updated to include my models.py with the model I want to call the logged in users data from

Answer (score 0):

Foreignkey is a Many-to-One relationship.So if you want to access all the logged-in users BarSignUp data, then you should do the following.

views.py

```
signups = request.user.barsignup_set.all()
```

template

```
{% for barsignup in signups %}
   {{ barsignup }}   
   {{ barsignup.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also there is an error in you BarSignUp **str**  method, please correct the same.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email  #if you want to display user email
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried this but am getting the error: "'User' object has no attribute 'BarSignUp_set'". This is what my code looks like: `def profile(request):

    user = request.user

    signups = request.user.BarSignUp_set.all()

    context = {
        "signups": signups,
    }

    return render (request, "profile.html", {})` template `{% for BarSignUp in signups %}
   {{ BarSignUp }}
   {{ BarSignUp.name }}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: use barsignup_set instead of BarSignUp_set  (problem with the case) - to refer to a reverse relationship, you need to use the lower case of the model name. So in your case it will be signups = request.user.barsignup_set.all()